# Maven container does not run if test / clean install / package command with args(-D) or profile tag (-P)

Tags: java, maven, docker

I tried to run my maven project into maven container but could not success. In windows i used to run my all test with following commands and it works fine but in "maven:3.6.3-jdk-8" container returns unknown life cycle error.

```
mvn clean install -Ptest OR mvn test -Ptest
```

> ```
> > [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "clean install". You must specify a
> > valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal>
> > or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>.
> > Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize,
> > generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources,
> > process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources,
> > process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources,
> > test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package,
> > pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify,
> > install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site,
> > post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
> ```

My POM.xml file.

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}\src\test\resources\project\test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>testMore</id>
            <properties>
                <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}\src\test\resources\project\testMore.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My dockerfile command

```
ENTRYPOINT  ["mvn", "test","-Ptest"]
```

OR

```
ENTRYPOINT  ["mvn", "clean install -P test"]
```

Whenever i replace `${suiteXmlFile}`with `${basedir}\src\test\resources\project\test.xml` and run `ENTRYPOINT  ["mvn", "test"]` container execute all the tests which are listed into test.xml.

i have already verified with -Dresources=test.xml it also don't work for me either, even i have tried with test and give goals / phase but no luck for me.

Comment: Entry point string must be split in individual words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you specified :

> ENTRYPOINT  ["mvn", "clean install -P test"]

is executed on the container as :

```
mvn "clean install -P test"
```

It considers `"clean install -P test"` as a single argument that is passed to
the maven program that doesn't consider the whole token "clean install -P test" as a valid lifecycle phase.

What you want with the exec form is :

```
ENTRYPOINT  ["mvn", "clean", "install", "-P", "test"]
```

or with the shell form :

```
ENTRYPOINT  mvn clean install -P test
```

[Docker entrypoint documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)